# Does Selenium support multiple browser windows running with different profiles?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing test automation for a web app. One of the supported capabilities of the product which I need to test is the following. Different users can be logged in on different machines at the same time, and when User 1 enters some data on Machine 1, the view for User 2 on Machine 2 automatically gets updated with that data, in real time, without needing to reload their browser.

I originally investigated using Selenium grid to control multiple machines to run these tests, but it didn't look like it was possible to have the specific steps run on specific machines in a certain order, which would be necessary.  So I am looking into running everything on one machine, using different Chrome profiles.

The example code I have so far looks like this:

```
var selenium1 = require('selenium-webdriver');
var selenium2 = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome1 = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const chrome2 = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var udd = "C:\\Users\\phil\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\";
var pd1 = "Profile 5";
var pd2 = "Profile 6";

const chromeOptions1 = new chrome1.Options();
chromeOptions1.addArguments(`user-data-dir=${udd}`);
chromeOptions1.addArguments(`profile-directory=${pd1}`);

const chromeOptions2 = new chrome2.Options();
chromeOptions2.addArguments(`user-data-dir=${udd}`);
chromeOptions2.addArguments(`profile-directory=${pd2}`);

var driver1 = new selenium1.Builder()
.forBrowser("chrome")
.setChromeOptions(chromeOptions1)
.build();

var driver2 = new selenium2.Builder()
.forBrowser("chrome")
.setChromeOptions(chromeOptions2)
.build();

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 90000;

describe('multiple browser test', function () {
    afterAll(async function () {
        await driver1.quit();
        await driver2.quit();
    });

    it('can open a web page', async function () {
            await driver1.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
            await driver2.get("http://www.bing.com");
            await driver1.sleep(5000);
            await driver2.sleep(5000);
    });
});
```

This appears to work, except for one thing.  When the line `await driver2.quit();` is called, I get an error:

`Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:[port number]`

and the second browser window does not close.

The questions are:

1. Is what I'm trying to do supported by Selenium?
2. If it is supported, is there anything obviously wrong with my code?  I've read many related questions here, and documentation elsewhere, but it looks like the process for making Selenium use a specific browser profile has changed over time, so I'm not 100% confident that what I have is correct now.
3. Where is that error message coming from, and what does it mean?  When I searched on that, it seemed to be related to Selenium Grid, which as I said before, I'm not using for this.

Comment: Short answer is no you cannot use multiple profiles (user-defined-dir) with multiple Chrome sessions. But, you can easily achieve what you want to achieve by using two different browser WebDriver instances (Chrome & FF for instance). If the profile can be worked around, you can use multiple tabs/windows with a single instance of Chrome.

Comment: That error message comes from the fact that you have created two sessions with your two drivers, but when you issue the `.quit` command it kills _the_ Chrome session. Then the second call to `.quit()` no longer has a session to close (a browser to connect to) - so the econnrefused error is generated.

Comment: So even though it is opening two different Chrome windows, and I duplicated everything that went into creating them (chrome, chromeOptions, driver, etc), there's still only one Chrome session underneath?  I never would have guessed that.  Good to know, thankee.

Comment: It isn't really one Chrome session, it is one Driver instance. It is the Selenium instance that has the problem.

Comment: It quite easy to open two Chrome windows/tabs and control them separately, you just can't have different `user-data-dir`'s

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/35548/34209

I believe the error your running into is not because of multiple drivers.